# iOS Swift intermittent crash with NSInvalidArgumentException when adding operation to CloudKit database

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, cloudkit

I have an intermittent crash that is happening infrequently after adding a CKModifyRecordsOperation to a ckdatabase. Here's the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[9]'

Here's the call stack:

```
*** First throw call stack:(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001090331cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107bcdf41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109072e8c _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108f416bd -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 237
4   Foundation                          0x0000000107624186 -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) encodeWithCoder:] + 841
5   Foundation                          0x00000001075d3132 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 578
6   CloudKit                            0x00000001073ca0f6 -[CKRecordValueStore encodeWithCoder:] + 105
7   Foundation                          0x00000001075d3132 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 578
8   CloudKit                            0x00000001073d2b9c -[CKRecord encodeWithCoder:] + 111
9   Foundation                          0x00000001075d3132 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 578
10  Foundation                          0x00000001075db9e3 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 221
11  Foundation                          0x00000001075d3132 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 578
12  CloudKit                            0x00000001074290a2 -[CKModifyRecordsOperationInfo encodeWithCoder:] + 128
13  Foundation                          0x00000001075d3132 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 578
14  Foundation                          0x0000000107756afb _NSXPCSerializationAddInvocationWithOnlyObjectArgumentsArray + 139
15  Foundation                          0x0000000107806279 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeInvocationObjectArgumentsOnly:count:typeString:selector:isReply:into:] + 199
16  Foundation                          0x0000000107804598 -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:] + 3155
17  Foundation                          0x0000000107803753 -[NSXPCConnection _sendSelector:withProxy:arg1:arg2:] + 125
18  Foundation                          0x000000010780f387 _NSXPCDistantObjectSimpleMessageSend2 + 46
19  CloudKit                            0x0000000107426615 -[CKModifyRecordsOperation performCKOperation] + 101
20  CloudKit                            0x00000001073ecb78 __19-[CKOperation main]_block_invoke + 807
21  CloudKit                            0x00000001073e8faf -[CKPlaceholderOperation main] + 34
22  CloudKit                            0x00000001073e8f61 -[CKPlaceholderOperation start] + 566
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d40343c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d408af4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d40343c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d408af4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d408884 dispatch_block_perform + 109
28  Foundation                          0x00000001075dece4 __NSOQSchedule_f + 342
29  libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib 0x0000000106216572 _ZN6__tsanL22dispatch_callback_wrapEPv + 306
30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d40343c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d409856 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 967
32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d407c86 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 780
33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d40f1f9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d40ee97 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d8c91ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
36  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d8c8c4d start_wqthread + 13)
```

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

And just for fun here's the process view (is that the right terminology?):

[image: Stack frame]

Immediately prior to instantiating the modify operation I'm printing out the CKRecord that I'm trying to save - it's identical when it crashes and when it doesn't. Here's the CKRecord when it crashed most recently (same record worked fine multiple times before the crash)

```
Optional([<CKRecord: 0x7b4400054600; recordID=x-coredata://B1B12FD0-C42B-4FA9-AAA1-B1003611D577/Item/p234:(OMG:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=1du, values={
category =     (
    "<CKReference: 0x7b0800067d20; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b0800069b20; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/Category/p19, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>"
);
ckID = "x-coredata://B1B12FD0-C42B-4FA9-AAA1-B1003611D577/Item/p234";
funNumber = 0;
list =     (
    "<CKReference: 0x7b0800036d20; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b0800068700; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/List/p1, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>"
);
modifiedDate = "2018-01-25 13:15:39 +0000";
name = Z;
quantity = 0;
status =     (
    "<CKReference: 0x7b0800069b40; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b0800069ee0; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/Status/p2, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>"
);
stores =     (
    "<CKReference: 0x7b0800038120; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b080001da60; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/Store/p1, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>"
);
unitType =     (
    "<CKReference: 0x7b080005e600; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b0800016180; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/UnitType/p1, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>"
); }, recordType=Item> {
creatorUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x7b080005a900; recordName=__defaultOwner__, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
lastModifiedUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x7b0800067800; recordName=__defaultOwner__, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
creationDate -> 2018-01-24 20:53:21 +0000
modificationDate -> 2018-01-25 13:15:38 +0000
modifiedByDevice -> iPhone
ckID (modified) -> "x-coredata://B1B12FD0-C42B-4FA9-AAA1-B1003611D577/Item/p234"
quantity (modified) -> 0 (type f)
status (modified) -> [<CKReference: 0x7b0800069b40; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b0800069ee0; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/Status/p2, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>]
modifiedDate (modified) -> 2018-01-25 13:15:39 +0000
category (modified) -> [<CKReference: 0x7b0800067d20; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b0800069b20; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/Category/p19, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>]
stores (modified) -> [<CKReference: 0x7b0800038120; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b080001da60; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/Store/p1, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>]
unitType (modified) -> [<CKReference: 0x7b080005e600; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b0800016180; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/UnitType/p1, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>]
list (modified) -> [<CKReference: 0x7b0800036d20; recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x7b0800068700; recordName=x-coredata://2EF4B094-5192-40B3-AA2A-17880E16E766/List/p1, zoneID=OMG:__defaultOwner__>>]
funNumber (modified) -> 0 (type q)
name (modified) -> "Z" }])
```

Here's where I instantiate the ckModifyRecordsOperation:

```
import Foundation
import CloudKit

class UploadChangesOperation: AsyncOperation {

var debug = true

let database: CKDatabase

var recordsToSave: [CKRecord]?
var recordIDsToDelete: [CKRecordID]?

var savedRecords: [CKRecord]?
var deletedRecordIDs: [CKRecordID]?

init(database: CKDatabase) {
    self.database = database
}

override func main() {

    super.main()

    guard recordsToSave != nil || recordIDsToDelete != nil else {
        if self.debug {
            print(" UploadChangesOperation - no uploads needed. ")
        }
        self.operationComplete()
        return
    }

    let completionBlockOperation = BlockOperation {
        if self.debug {
            print(" UploadChangesOperation complete ")
        }
        self.operationComplete()
    }

    print("Num of recordsToSave: \(String(describing: recordsToSave?.count))")
    print(recordsToSave as Any)

    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: recordsToSave, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsToDelete)

    // TODO: modify this depending on whether the user initited vs we received a notification

    operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
    operation.isAtomic = false

    operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { record, error in

        if error != nil {

            // FIXME: Error handling

            if self.debug {
                print(" UploadChangesOperation perRecordCompletionBlock error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }

            //let _ = CloudKitError.share.handle(error: error, operation: .modifyRecords, affectedObjects: [record] as [Any], alert: false)

        } else {

            if self.debug {
                print(" UploadChangesOperation perRecordCompletionBlock fires for \(String(describing: record.value(forKey: Schema.GenericFieldNames.name)))")
            }

            if self.savedRecords != nil {
                self.savedRecords?.append(record)
            } else {
                self.savedRecords = [record]
            }
         }
    }

    operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, deletedRecordIDs, error in

        if error != nil {

            if self.debug {
                print(" UploadChangesOperation modifyRecordsCompletionBlock ERROR WILL ROBINSON!!")
                print(" \(String(describing: error))")
            }

            //let _ = CloudKitError.share.handle(error: error, operation: .modifyRecords, affectedObjects: records, alert: false)

        } else {

            self.deletedRecordIDs = deletedRecordIDs

        }

        self.backgroundQueue.addOperation(completionBlockOperation)
    }

    self.database.add(operation)

}
}
```

I've totally hit a wall and have been banging my head on it for days now. I'm *assuming* that the record is the problem somehow (objects[9] lines up nearly with the 10 fields I have in my CKRecord and it always gives that exact error), but I'm not really sure how to check that - it looks fine when I instantiate the CKModifyRecordsOperation, it looks fine before and after I add the operation to the database...

Any help at all, big or small, is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Which line in the code causes the crash? Can you post the fields in this CKRecord?

Comment: @Bill thanks for the comment.  Debugging this problem is probably beyond the scope of a forum like this.  The sync system  I'm building is using Operations + I'm new to operations and concurrency.  I finally figured out that my CKRecords were sometimes being deallocated between the time I add the CKModifyRecordsOperation to the database and when it actually fires.  I hadn't really considered this was even possible.  After doing a bunch more reading and research I'm once again refactoring the system and I'm assuming this specific bug will disappear and 10+ new ones will show up. Thanks again.